# Querying SQL using a Code column vs extended table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I am setting up a fairly large dataset (catalogue) on a sql database (i'd guesstimate ∼100k records) to store information regarding products. Each product is characterized by about 20-30 properties, so that would basically mean 20-30 column. The system is setup so that each of these properties is actually linked to a code, and each product is therefore characterized by a unique string made concatenating all these properties (the string has to be unique, if two product codes are the same then the two products are actually the same product).  What I am trying to figure out is if sql-wise there is any difference to storing the catalogue as a table of 20-30 columns, or if I am better off just having 1 column with the code and decoding the properties from the code. The difference being that in one case I would do

```
SELECT * FROM Catalogue WHERE Color='RED'
```

versus

```
SELECT * FROM Catalogue WHERE Code LIKE '____R____________'
```

Also it might make it easier to check whether a product already exists, as I am only comparing a single column compared to 20-30 columns. I could also just add an extra column to the complete table to store the code and use one method when doing one operation and another when doing another operation.

I have almost no knowledge of how the SQL engine works so I might be completely off with my reasoning here.

Comment: If each "code" is a separate entity, and would be queried separately, they should be stored separately. The former query in the above, with the correct index, would likely only need a seek for the relevant rows. The latter query, however, isn't SARGable, due to the leading wild card(s) and so the **entire** table would need to be scanned; which is far less performant,

Comment: To a first approximation, you are almost always worse off by combining logically distinct pieces of data into one column that has to be decoded again. The operations needed to pack/unpack values slow down queries and preclude the use of indexes. There are rare cases where it helps with storage, but even there you're usually better off using data compression (whether row or page). If the combined column itself is often queried for as a whole, make it a computed column with an index on it.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but: 100k rows is considered small these days. Definitely not "fairly large"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code` approach seems silly.  Why do I phrase it this way?

You have a few dozen columns with attributes and you *know* what they are.  Why would you NOT include that information in the data model.

I am also amused by how you are going to distinguish these comparisons:

```
WHERE Code LIKE '____R____________'
WHERE Code LIKE '___R_____________'
WHERE Code LIKE '_____R___________'
WHERE Code LIKE '____R___________'
```

That just seems like a recipe for spending half the rest of your future life on debugging -- if not your code then someone else's.

And, with separate columns, you can create indexes for commonly used combinations.

If not all rows have all attributes -- or if the attributes can be expanded in the future -- you might want a structure with a separate line for each attribute:

```
entityId     code      value
   1         Color     Red
```

This is called an entity-attribute-value (EAV) model and is appropriate under some circumstances.

Comment: Yeah I realized the code approach was a bit weird, the thing is I actually HAVE to have the code, so I thought I might as well use it, the code should be somewhat standard (e.g. first three letters are the color, next three the material...) so i figured creating a method to build the string from a list of filters wasn't going to be that hard, the code might actually be separated by hyphens or something similar (I still need to receive the details). Thanks for the reply though, I'll proceed the standard way:)

Comment: Also by the way, the properties shouldn't change, and they should all be always filled, but just as extra info isn't querying in an EAV model slower? (suppose I have to propose options to a user while he is filling out a form, suggesting commonly used property values based on similar products, and therefore need a fairly quick response time).

Comment: @NicoloCastro . . . If you know all the properties in advance and they are not going to change, then a the flexibility that the EAV model provides is not helpful.  And such data structures are usually less efficient performance-wise.